# Fixed point division numbers

Tags: verilog

I have a little problem . I want to do a program that divides two numbers with fixed point . My output looks okay but when I test the program on a 
local test site I get some strange results. Can someone help me?Thanks.

```
module divider(
        input[7:0] a,b,
        output reg [15:0] q,
        output reg [7:0] r,frac
          );

        reg[7:0] c2, r2;
        integer c;
    always @(*)
        begin

        c = 8'b00000000;
        r = a;
          frac = 8'b00000000;

        repeat (30)
            begin
               if (r >= b )
                  begin
                    c = c + 1;
                    r = r - b;
                  end
             end

          q[15:8] = c;



        repeat (8)
        begin
          if(r != 0)
                begin
                r = r*10;
                c2 = 8'b00000000;

                repeat(30)
                    begin

                    if (r>=b)
                        begin
                        c2 = c2 + 1;
                        r = r-b;
                        end
                    end
                frac = frac*10 + c2;
                end
            end

             q[7:0] = frac;








end

endmodule
```

Output local site:

```
error: a =   1, b =   2, q = 0.019531, expected q = 0.500000
error: a =   1, b =   4, q = 0.097656, expected q = 0.250000
error: a =   1, b =   5, q = 0.007813, expected q = 0.199219
error: a =   1, b =   7, q = 0.570313, expected q = 0.140625
error: a =   1, b =   8, q = 0.488281, expected q = 0.125000
error: a =   1, b =   9, q = 0.777344, expected q = 0.109375
error: a =   1, b =  10, q = 0.003906, expected q = 0.097656
error: a =   1, b =  11, q = 0.363281, expected q = 0.089844
error: a =   1, b =  14, q = 0.785156, expected q = 0.070313
error: a =   1, b =  15, q = 0.664063, expected q = 0.066406
error: a =   1, b =  16, q = 0.441406, expected q = 0.062500
error: a =   1, b =  17, q = 0.937500, expected q = 0.058594
error: a =   1, b =  18, q = 0.386719, expected q = 0.054688
error: a =   1, b =  19, q = 0.207031, expected q = 0.050781
error: a =   1, b =  20, q = 0.019531, expected q = 0.046875
error: a =   1, b =  21, q = 0.187500, expected q = 0.046875
error: a =   1, b =  22, q = 0.679688, expected q = 0.042969
error: a =   1, b =  23, q = 0.695313, expected q = 0.042969
error: a =   1, b =  25, q = 0.015625, expected q = 0.039063
error: a =   1, b =  27, q = 0.589844, expected q = 0.035156
error: a =   1, b =  28, q = 0.890625, expected q = 0.035156
error: a =   1, b =  29, q = 0.824219, expected q = 0.031250
error: a =   1, b =  30, q = 0.832031, expected q = 0.031250
error: a =   1, b =  31, q = 0.804688, expected q = 0.031250
error: a =   1, b =  32, q = 0.207031, expected q = 0.031250
error: a =   1, b =  33, q = 0.121094, expected q = 0.027344
error: a =   1, b =  34, q = 0.437500, expected q = 0.027344
error: a =   1, b =  35, q = 0.570313, expected q = 0.027344
error: a =   1, b =  36, q = 0.914063, expected q = 0.027344
error: a =   1, b =  37, q = 0.000000, expected q = 0.023438
error: a =   1, b =  38, q = 0.339844, expected q = 0.023438
error: a =   1, b =  40, q = 0.097656, expected q = 0.023438
```

Comment: Not 100% sure how this algorithm is support to work; but if you run through your first example, you'll find that the produced `q` makes sense from what you are doing. Note that this design describes completely combinational logic which may or may not be your intent. Im not sure where you got `repeat (30)` from as you can see with example `a = 8'd100`, `b = 8'd2`, `c` will be 30 at the end of the first loop as you wont have done enough successive subtraction. Also note that fixed point is typically base two, not base ten as you have here (`fact = fact*10 + c2`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need radix 10 for division on FPGA. Radix2 division (e.g. [shift and subtract](https://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/BuildingBlocks/divide.030.html)) would be much faster and easier to implement. I found [this](http://www.arithmetic-circuits.org/FixedPointDivision/FixedPointDivision.html) example for radix2 division.